# How can i do async numbers sorting app WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to make an app that loads numbers from files chosen by the user and shows sorting results on the screen. but I have few problems, the biggest is sorting, I mean it must be in asynchronous because "it's better for UI" and I'm not sure I did well rest of the job especially I'm thinking about connecting everything together. HELP PLEASE

ViewModel

```
sealed class numbersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        

        private numbersModel user;
        public string NumbersString
        {
            get { return user.NumbersString + user.NumbersString; }
            set
            { 
                    user.NumbersString = value;
                    OnPropertyChange("numbers1");
                    OnPropertyChange("numbers2");
                    OnPropertyChange("numbers3");
                    OnPropertyChange("numbers4");
                    OnPropertyChange("numbers5");
                
            }
        }
        public List<string> NumbersList
        {
            get { return user.NumbersList = stringToList(user.NumbersString); }
        }
        public string SortedNumbers
        {
            get { return sortingNumbers(user.NumbersList); }
        }

        public string sortingNumbers(List<string> l)
        {
            string sorted = "";
            l.Sort();
            foreach (string g in l)
            {
                sorted = sorted + g + "  , ";
            }
            return sorted;
        }
        
        


        List<string> stringToList(string ex)
        {

            string number = "";

            List<string> numberList = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ex.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((Char.IsDigit(ex[i])) || (ex[i] == '.') || ex[i] == ',')
                {
                    if ((Char.IsDigit(ex[i])) || (ex[i] == '.'))
                    {
                        number = number + ex[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        number = number + ".";
                    }
                    if (i == ex.Length - 1)
                    {
                        numberList.Add(number);
                        number = "";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == 0) { }

                    else
                    {
                        if (Char.IsDigit(ex[i - 1]))
                        {
                            numberList.Add(number);
                            number = "";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            return numberList;
        }
```

Model

```
sealed class numbersModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        
        public string NumbersString { get; set; }

        public List<string> NumbersList { get; set; }

        public string SortedNumbersList { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML

I have 10 buttons like this

```
<Button Name="_1btn1" Background="Pink" Grid.Column="0"
                                            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
                                            Click="btn_Click" ClickMode="Press"
                                            Width="120" Height="30" >
                                        Load File
                                    </Button>
```

and 10 text blocks like this, it shows there a text from the file but not sort I have to not sort it for single files. I think there is a mistake with property changed method but I dunno

```
<ScrollViewer
                                    Width="500"
                                    Height="50"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                        <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="numbers1" Text="{Binding null, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                FontSize="15"
                                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                                Width="Auto"                                               
                                                Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
```

This is the main text block where I have to show results

```
TextBlock  
        Height="400" Background="Aqua" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SortedNumbers}">
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: `it must be in asynchronyous because "its better for UI"` not quite. `asynchronous` doesn't mean "run in the background" which is what you really want here. It means `don't block while waiting for something else to happen`. The reason you need to avoid long operations on the UI thread is that the UI appears stuck while that operation takes place. Unless you have *thousands* of entries though, a simple `List.Sort` won't take long enough to affect the UI.

Comment: The *really* expensive operation is concatenating strings, not sorting. Each concatenation creates a new temporary string. You can replace all this code with a simple call to `String.Join(" ,",someList)`. I suspect `stringToList` can be replaced either with a simple `String.Split` or a regular expression.

Comment: BTW there's nothing asynchronous in the posted code. Everything runs on the UI thread, raising a lot of PropertyChanged events for non-existent properties. Are you trying to display a list of text blocks perhaps, one for each item on the list?

Comment: it must be asynchronyous because the content of the task says that sorting must be asynchronys. @PanagiotisKanavos i know thers nothing asynhronous i was trying but i dont know how to make sorting asynhronus. i didint post all code, i have 5 buttons and 5 text blocks, buttons load txt files from system and text blocks shows whats inside, my app have to take all numbers from files that user choosed (it doesnt have to be 5, may be 2 or 3 etc) and sort all these numbers and show on the textblock(last code)

Comment: What content, what task? What is the *actual* question? What you posted is rather confusing. If you wanted to display a list of items you should [use a `ListView` or something similar](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) and *bind it to a collection property* instead of specifying the trigger. Binding can be asynchronous if needed (all it takes is setting a flag) but that won't make the *operation* that generates the data asynchronous. Check the [ListView doc page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-overview)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the task is: Make a simple sorting program which loads few .txt files, sort all numbers from them (not for every single file) and show these numbers on interface. You have to use MVVM, and asynchronyous sorting.

Comment: The article [How to: Sort a GridView Column When a Header Is Clicked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-sort-a-gridview-column-when-a-header-is-clicked) shows how to add sorting in the GridView itself. If you want sorting itself to be asynchronous you can use `await Task.Run(()=>someList.Sort())`, eg in the command handler